# Parallax Scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I'm trying to incorporate parallax scrolling to my background where it moves at a slower rate relative to the web page content. I've been following tutorials but nothing is working I am stuck. Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/batLeeyw/24/

and here is the javascript. Sorry I have a lot of html / CSS so I will leave that in the fiddle link. Also my background image is not showing up in fiddle but it is static when its supposed to parallax in the browser.

```
function parallax(){
            var para = document.getElementById("parallax-layer");
            para.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+"px";
        }

        window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

Comment: Maybe if you spelled "document" without the extra 'e' in it.

Comment: Check your console output; you have an error in your code.

Comment: @Herohtar No error..

Comment: @DanielBeck Wow thanks but still not working.

Comment: Hi Ryder, please add a [mcve] to your question. As it is now, it risks being closed due to being incomplete based on what's in the question itself. (Specifically, links to JSFiddle are great, *but* we require you to include at least enough code for a minimal repro of the scenario/error in the question itself for times when sites like JSFiddle/CodePen go down and render the question otherwise useless/unanswerable).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your goal exactly is, but try this:

remove:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

from the `#parallax-layer` id in the css.
Change your js to:

```
function parallax(){
         var newtop = (window.pageYOffset / 2);
         $("#parallax-layer").css({top: newtop + 'px'});
         }

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

See the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/batLeeyw/47/) in the fiddle.

With `background-attachment: fixed` the image will not move because it is, like the property says, fixed. It's just cutted.

The new js is just a little bit different, I used more jQuery and changed the 4 -> 2. So it scrolls slower than before.
Hope that's what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your CSS syntax, you need to just add `http://` before your image url:

`background-image: url(http://link);`

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/batLeeyw/23/)

Comment: Thanks! but I still need help getting it to be parallax.